# genfromtxt : read ints from space separated .txt file

Tags: python, numpy

I just want to read 4 ints(matrix 4 cols, lots of rows) from file in numpy array.

Data looks like:

```
74  85  123 1
73  84  122 1
72  83  121 1
70  81  119 1
70  81  119 1
69  80  118 1
70  81  119 1
```

Code:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('Skin_NonSkin.txt', dtype=(int, int, int, int), delimiter=' ')
```

But I get error

```
    data = np.genfromtxt('Skin_NonSkin.txt', dtype=(int, int, int, int), delimiter=' ')
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1760, in genfromtxt
    rows = np.array(data, dtype=[('', _) for _ in dtype_flat])
ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.
```

Comment: You don't need a delimiter, just  `np.genfromtxt('Skin_NonSkin.txt', dtype=(int, int, int, int))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  hmm, it works.

Comment: You have more than one space so passing the delimiter can give weird output, if you use the four lines in your input, put two spaces in between each your file and pass the `delimiter=" "` you will see different output. From the docs *By default, any consecutive whitespaces act as delimiter.* It is basically the difference between `str.split(" ")` and `str.split()`

Comment: Closing this since it has no answer and is fully covered by the other question.