# Read ints from .txt file into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, text, genfromtxt

I'm tring to read 4 ints from simple .txt array as described in this question
[genfromtxt : read ints from space separated .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255001/genfromtxt-read-ints-from-space-separate-txt-file)

but I want it as 2D numpy array.

```
def read_data():
    data = np.genfromtxt('Skin_NonSkin.txt', dtype=(int, int, int, int))

    print type(data)
    print data.shape
    print data[0]
    print type(data[0])
    print data[0].shape
    print data[0][1]

    return data
```

it gives me

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(245057L,)
(74, 85, 123, 1)
<type 'numpy.void'>
()
85
```

So how to properly read the data or convert it to 2D nampy array with shape (245057,4)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('Skin_NonSkin.txt', dtype=np.int32)
```

You are creating a 1D array of `(int,int,int,int)` but what you really want is a 2D array of `np.int32`.